# Create array of object properties

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects, like this:

```
[
    {
        name: 'Gary',
        job: 'Janitor'
    },{
        name: 'Bill',
        job: 'Dancer'
    },{
        name: 'Barry',
        job: 'Black Smith'
    }
]
```

I'd like to create an array of values for the job property, so I want to end up with this:

```
[
    'Janitor',
    'Dancer',
    'Black Smith'    
]
```

I'd like to use only vanilla JS to accomplish this.

What would be the best approach to accomplish this?

Comment: `arr.map(x => x.job )`

Comment: Have a look at `map`. You can pass a function like `person => person.job` to it to accomplish this

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the advice.